# Is it possible to insert interarrival times on a source block based on a database?

Tags: anylogic

In my model I want the source block to generate trucks based on the frequency of the interarrivals calculated from a dataset. I have organized my Excel sheet with 2 columns: the first one with the different possible interarrival times and the second with the frequency of those said times. I have already imported the table into AnyLogic but now don't know how to proceed in order to change the Source Block taking into account the dataset.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwEsm.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jygJ5.png)

Initially, I was using a fixed interarrival time of 30 minutes but now I need to change it to make it real according to the data in the dataset.

Comment: can you clarify the diff between IAT and frequency? What exactly do you want to achieve? Also, what have you tried already?

Comment: IAT is the time between truck A arriving and truck B arriving. The frequency is the amount of times each interval happens
Haven't tried that much, we are a group of students so we are quite new to the program

Comment: What does this mean: "The frequency is the amount of times each interval happens" ? I genuinely don't understand this. Either you have an IAT or a frequency, how can you have both?

Comment: Also, welcome to SOF and AnyLogic. Some tips to get good help: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community . And here some special notes on SOF, this requires a bit more care: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the misunderstanding. We have now changed our dataset so that it only contains one column with all the IAT. We are still struggling in inserting the new datsaet into Anylogic, so we would appreciate some help :)
Thank you for the links!

Comment: Always open a new issue for new questions, or edit this one. Pls provide enough details and avoid "how do I do X" questions here on SOF, that is what LinkedIn is better for. Use SOF for "I tried X but got this error, how can I fix that"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is to use a custom distribution, add that table of frequencies to the custom distribution, and use the customDistribution() function in the interarrival time

Answer (score 0):

try using a [Schedule object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4RNR.png) to feed the Source.
This is [how you configure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHwAl.png) it.
You can also fill the schedule from DB if you want.